# how can we raise Salesforce Sites hours

Tags: apex, force.com-sites

i am facing a issue for salesforce sites function. As i know, salesforce sites function in production org  have 60h per day. but, my customer said that the 60 hours pre day can not match the requirement. After i try to get some answer from google. looks like not get any information.

So, my question is

1, if pay the money, can SFDC raise the hours per day.

2, If there some other ways for publish data to vf page. And i can get data without login.

Comment: Are you referring to the [Service Request Time (per rolling 24-hour period per site)](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_limits.htm&language=en_US) limit?

Comment: You can log in as a guest user, but you'd still be serving the data using visual force pages. See the page @BarCotter referenced which gives you billing options and methods of caching pages to reduce your usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you need to understand is this is rolling limit .Means if site remains without hit for sometime these limits starts rolling back .

You can surely contact salesforce for increasing these I believe .You can discuss with your account executive .Please note I am not salesforce employee to confirm that they agree but in past for a client I had managed to get it increased .

Also using cache attribute to true will help in preventing this limit to reach.